# Административные округа Москвы это distrcit или area?

Tags: geocoding, yandex-geocoding-api

Стоит задача: по координатам определить к какой административно-территориальной единице города относится точка.

Соответственно запрос формируется с атрибутом: **geocoder_kind=district**

Но в ходе экспериментов выяснилось, что точки внутри НАО и ТАО на такой запрос отдают ничего, например запрос для точки координаты которой дают Яндекс.Карты по запросу "Новомосковский административный округ" (55.558121, 37.370724):

https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/search//v1/?callback=id_152207300832331696006&text=55.558121%2C37.370724&format=json&rspn=0&lang=ru_RU&token=7df388b84269acd1dc9ca38e72a98f2d&type=geo&properties=addressdetails&geocoder_sco=latlong&geocoder_kind=district&origin=jsapi2Geocoder&spn=&sign=173791618

В ходе экспериментов, оказалось, что НАО и ТАО, в отличии от всех остальных АО Москвы, это **kind: area**, тогда как все остальные АО это **kind: district**

Это ошибка, или так было задумано?.. и теперь придется костылять приложуху с учетом этой информации?

Comment: Каким образом вы формируете этот запрос?

Comment: ymaps.geocode(coords, {kind:'district'})

Answer (score 1):

Такая иерархия компонентов адреса связана с правила адресации в Москве и Новой Москве:

- В старой Москве округ не является непосредственной частью адреса (дома адресуются просто улицей и городом, например, "Москва, улица Льва Толстого, 16")
- в Новой Москве округа также включают в себе *поселения*, которые являются неотъемлемой частью адреса, например, "Москва, поселение Сосенское, улица Александры Монаховой, 99"

Чтобы корректно передать эту логику в адресных объектах Геокодера, появляется описанное вами изменение в типизации - это отражение фактической ситуации с адресами в Москве.